# Parsing Boolean JSON value is always giving me false

Tags: android, json

I am getting the following JSON:

```
    {
    "ID": "479",
    "id": "479",
    "name": "Nishant Kango",
    "last_logged": "1461225061",
    "current_status": "icon-online prople-online",
    "room_id": "d18f655c3fce66ca401d5f38b48c89af",
    "current_user": false,
    "lastmessage": [],
    "userInfo": {
        "id": "479",
        "birthday": "1989-11-21",
        "comment_privacy": "everyone",
        "confirm_followers": "1",
        "current_city": "Chandigarh, Chandigarh",
        "follow_privacy": "everyone",
        "gender": "male",
        "hometown": null,
        "message_privacy": "everyone",
        "timeline_post_privacy": "a:1:{i:0;s:1:\"1\";}",
        "feed_section": "1",
        "post_privacy": "a:1:{i:0;s:1:\"5\";}",
        "current_city_id": "1433",
        "userSkills": ", Testing ",
        "birth": {
            "date": "21",
            "month": "11",
            "year": "1989"
        },
        "about": "asdasdasdas sad asd asd asd as",
        "active": "1",
        "avatar_id": "477",
        "cover_id": "528",
        "cover_position": "465",
        "email": "nishantkango@yahoo.co.in",
        "email_verification_key": null,
        "email_verified": "0",
        "language": null,
        "last_logged": "1461225061",
        "name": "Nishant Kango",
        "time": "0",
        "timestamp": "2016-04-21 13:19:40",
        "timezone": null,
        "type": "user",
        "username": "nishant",
        "verified": false,
        "user_id": "479",
        "first_name": "Nishant",
        "middle_name": null,
        "last_name": "Kango",
        "dob": "1989-11-21",
        "mobile": "8699022278",
        "title": null,
        "marital_status": "single",
        "childrens": "0",
        "hobbies": "Travelling",
        "interests": "Technology",
        "feed_back": null,
        "status": "approved",
        "profile_pic": null,
        "date_created": "2014-10-29 00:00:00",
        "date_modified": "2016-03-31 19:07:56",
        "activation_code": null,
        "social_login_type": "facebook",
        "facebook_id": "10205077190793111",
        "linked_in_id": null,
        "google_id": null,
        "employment_status": null,
        "is_deleted": "0",
        "website": "http://www.nishantkango.com",
        "reference_institute": "",
        "industry": "0",
        "proffesion_type": "",
        "url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/user/timeline/e6b34e9a0311a7f829e09d2d7c4b313e",
        "cover": {
            "id": "528",
            "active": "1",
            "album_id": "0",
            "extension": "jpg",
            "name": "mentordirectorybgimagesuggestions6.jpg",
            "post_id": "0",
            "temp": "0",
            "timeline_id": "0",
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "common/marvel/photos/2016/02/hqUDT_528_f4be00279ee2e0a53eafdaa94a151e2c",
            "complete_url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/common/marvel/photos/2016/02/hqUDT_528_f4be00279ee2e0a53eafdaa94a151e2c.jpg",
            "post_url": "/index.php?tab1=story&id=0"
        },
        "actual_cover_url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/common/marvel/photos/2016/02/hqUDT_528_f4be00279ee2e0a53eafdaa94a151e2c.jpg",
        "cover_url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/common/marvel/photos/2016/02/hqUDT_528_f4be00279ee2e0a53eafdaa94a151e2c_cover.jpg",
        "avatar": {
            "id": "477",
            "active": "1",
            "album_id": "0",
            "extension": "jpg",
            "name": "10390233_10205765787487598_5674312231016706405_n.jpg",
            "post_id": "0",
            "temp": "0",
            "timeline_id": "0",
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "common/marvel/photos/2016/01/yS1xw_477_74071a673307ca7459bcf75fbd024e09",
            "complete_url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/common/marvel/photos/2016/01/yS1xw_477_74071a673307ca7459bcf75fbd024e09.jpg",
            "post_url": "/index.php?tab1=story&id=0"
        },
        "thumbnail_url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/common/marvel/images/default-male-avatar.png",
        "avatar_url": "http://192.168.2.250:82/common/marvel/images/default-male-avatar.png",
        "online": true
    }
}
```

I have to check the online/offine status of a user using online key inside the userInfo object.I am using the following code :

```
JSONObject userInfo = object.getJSONObject("userInfo");
 Boolean online = userInfo.getBoolean("online");
Log.e("Online",online);
```

When i tried to use this statement :

```
Log.e("online1", (String) userInfo.get("online"));
```

It gives me the error that java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String .

So it is sure that userInfo.get("online") is returning me some boolean value.So when i use this :

```
Log.e("online1", String.valueOf(userInfo.getBoolean("online")));
```

it gives me always false but i know i am getting true value from server in some cases.Please help me to fix the issue

Comment: This must work.. Are you sure you are doing everything like this?

Comment: You can try to put boolean, the property, and not Boolean, the object.

Comment: Everything is fine with code, make sure that you are executing same code.

Comment: @DanielShatz: Yes i am using the same code.

Comment: @Ahsanwarsi:Yes ,i am executing same code

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain the `get()` function returns a `boolean`. I am not certain about the JSON library with Android but ones I have used will return the value as a string for which you then need to parse using `Boolean.parseBoolean(value)`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: When i tried to use this statement :   Log.e("online1", (String) userInfo.get("online")); It gives me the error that java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String .So it is sure that userInfo.get("online") is returning me some boolean value.So when i use this :  Log.e("online1", String.valueOf(userInfo.getBoolean("online"))); it gives me always false but i know i am getting true value from server in some cases.Please help me to fix the issue

Comment: Ok... you get the error because `Boolean` is a wrapper class for the primitive time, so you cannot just simply cast it. To print it in your log you will need to use `userinfo.get("online").toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> Boolean online = Boolean.parseBoolean(userInfo.getString("online"))

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Log.e("Online", online.toString());
```

It takes only String.

The method e(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean).

Answer (score 0):

you try boolean online = userInfo.getBoolean("online"); instead of Boolean online = userInfo.getBoolean("online");

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `opt` version instead of the `get` version.

The main difference is that `opt` will not throw a `JSONException` and stop parsing.

Try therefore to replace all of your `getXXX()` by `optXXX()`.

Another upside is that with `opt`, you can specify a fallback value.

Comment: Potentially not, if the `JSONException` is raised before fetching the value the OP is looking for, then that value will never get parsed.

Comment: The OP probably wants to process the errors in JSON

Comment: Without much explanation from him, we can't be sure. Overall, `opt` is a safer option, because it can skip values not present in the response, but will still go up till the end. Furthermore, the code the OP wrote here wouldn't produce the output he's facing, which means that most likely comes from somewhere else in the code.